# How to show the matrix $\left( \binom{x-i}{j-1}\right)_{1\leq i,j\leq 2r+1}$ has determinant (-1)^r and it's inverse?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, determinant, inverse

After playing around in mathematica,  I found that the matrix $\left( \binom{x-i}{j-1}\right)_{1\leq i,j\leq 2r+1}$ has determinant $(-1)^r$ for the first few $r$'s.

How can I prove this this, or at the very least prove it in general has nonzero determinant? Are there are general methods to get a closed form for the inverse?

Comment: Which is it, ${x-i \choose j}$ or ${x-i \choose j-1}$?

Comment: It boils down to a Vandermonde-like matrix by replacing every column with a linear combination of that column and the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with entries ${x-i \choose j-1}$, $i,j=1..n$, and $E$ the lower triangular matrix $n \times n$ with entries 
$(-1)^{i+j} {i-1 \choose j-1}$, then it seems that
$E M$ is upper triangular with alternating $\pm 1$ on the diagonal.  This boils down to some binomial identities.

Comment: Yea I just checked! How did you come up with that so fast? I also noticed that EM is its own inverse, so M^{-1}= EME?  Not sure how to prove these things tho.